# Topological space with only finitely many neighborhoods at every point

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set.

Can you give me an example of a topology on $X$ such that every point $x \in X$ has between $2$ and $n_x$ neighborhoods?

Comment: In $\Bbb R$, declare the open sets to be $\emptyset$, $\Bbb R$, and $\{1\}$. (This may qualify as "trivial".)

Comment: @DavidMitra Good comment. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

This first part relates to an older version of the question (which I think is of interest).

Yes, there are non-trivial infinite spaces where every point has only finitely many open neighbourhoods. A nice example of such a space is the "right order topology" on $\mathbb{N}$: the open sets are final segements of $\mathbb{N}$: $A_n = \{ n, n+1 , n+2 , \ldots \}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it follows that $A_0 , \ldots , A_n$ are the only open neighbourhoods of $n$.

Note that in such a space it follows that arbitrary intersections of open sets are open.  (If $\bigcap_{i \in I} U_i \neq \emptyset$, then each $U_i$ is an open neighbourhood of each of the points in the intersection, and so only finitely many distinct sets are amongst the $U_i$, and it is therefore open).  Such a space is also called an [Alexandrov space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology).  In such spaces, every point $x \in X$ has a smallest open neighbourhood $U_x$, and the relation $$x \leq y \Leftrightarrow x \in U_y$$ defines a quasi-order on $X$ (it is reflexive and transitive, but may fail to be anti-symmetric).

(Note that in the example above, the quasi-order associated to the topology is the reverse of the usual ordering.)

Furthermore, given a quasi-order $\leq$ on a set $X$ we can define a topology on $X$ by taking the basic open sets to be of the form $V_x := \{ y \in X : y \leq x \}$ for each $x \in X$.  Note that given $x , y \in X$ we have that $V_x = V_y$ iff $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$. We will call such elements of $X$ *equivalent*.

Back to the (original)  problem, since each $x$ has only finitely many neighbourhoods, it follows that for each $x \in X$ there are only finitely many non-equivalent $y \in X$ such that $y \not\leq x$.  (This is because if $y , z$ are non-equivalent and $y,z \not\leq x$, it follows that $V_x \cup V_y$ are $V_x \cup V_z$ are distinct open neighbourhoods of $x$.)

---

On to the modified question.

If $X$ is infinite, partition it into two disjoint nonempty sets $A , B$, and consider the topology $\{ \varnothing , A , B , X \}$.  For each $x \in A$ the only open neighbourhoods of $x$ are $A , X$, and similarly for $x \in B$.  Thus every point has exactly $2$ open neighbourhoods.

The (not very interesting) quasi-order $\leq$ corresponding to this topology is given by
$$x \leq y \leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
x \in A\;\&\;y \in A; &\text{or} \\
x \in B\;\&\;y \in B
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Include finitely many subsets of $X$ in the topology. If you need every point to have a neighborhood $\neq X$ take the subsets so that their union is $X$.

For edited question-
 Take $X=\Bbb N$ ,take the sets $\{1\}$,$\{2,3,4...\}$ as open sets this ensures that every point has exactly 2 neighborhoods.

Comment: I edited the question. Can you give a concrete example?